# Custom automated campaign not showing in Send Email Campaign Message Action

Tags: exm, sitecore-forms

I am using `Sitecore 9 Update 1 Forms`. I have created a custom automated campaign to send on form button click but I am not able to see my newly created campaign in `Send Email Campaign Message Action`.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you verify on the Form_EXM item that the `Message Type` field says "Automated message" and the `State` field is "Active"? Both fields are in the `System` section of the item.

Comment: Where is a option to set Active in Email Experience Manager?

Comment: On the delivery tab of your message in EXM.. if this is your issue I'll explain in an answer with screenshots

Comment: Yes after change state to active in content tree it is working but I want to active from Email Experience Manager. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should check that your message is "Automated" and "Active". You can do this in 2 ways:

- in the `Content Editor` check the `System` section of your message item : [image]
- or, and better, in EXM:

  - Go to the "automated email campaigns" in the main navigation on the left
  - Find your message (it should be in there if it was an automated one)
  - Click the message to go to the details and check the campaign info:[image]

If this is not Active, you can click on "Full email campaign" (on the right between the preview and the info pane). This will enable you to edit the properties - go to the delivery tab and set the message as active (click on the  "Activate message" button). It should look like this afterwards:
[image]